# Struts2 submit tags

Tags: java, struts2, struts

New to struts2 and ran into a question and need clarification. Hope the experts to help me a bit

I am writing a beginners struts program using tags, i am using tag prefix 's'
I have created JSP page where you can upload a file, I have logic to check if the file is present or if its null based on the input I display accordingly. When no file is uploaded, I put the user of a `retry.jsp` page with ERROR MSG: "You have not selected any file, please select a file and try upload"  and I have button with value="Go back to upload page" the following is the logic I have in my retry.jsp:

```
<s:form action="Goback" method="post">
<s:submit value="Go back to upload page"/>
</s:form>
```

So would like to know if there is any way to call the "Goback" action with out using form and by just using a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [an anchor (`<s:a>`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16900840/1654265) or a button triggering a javascript function to make a POST or a GET without using a `<form>`.

BTW in your case I would step back a bit and rethink the logic:

you can put your requirement (a file must be uploaded) in Struts2 validation, so that when a form will be posted without a file, it will return an `INPUT` result from the ValidationInterceptor, instead of reaching the Action (and returning `SUCCESS` after executing the method), going back to the same page (or to another, if required, but generally it is not), and notifying the error to user through an automatic populated `fieldError`.

You can do it in XML, with Annotations or with pure Java in the `validate()` method. 
Follow the example (when no result is specified, SUCCESS is used):

---

Struts.xml

```
<action name="SourceAction" class="xxx.yyy.SourceAction">
    <result>source.jsp</result>
</action>

<action name="TargetAction" class="xxx.yyy.TargetAction">
    <result>target.jsp</result>
    <result name="input">source.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Source Action

```
public class SourceAction extends ActionSupport 

    public String execute(){
        return SUCCESS;
    }

}
```

Source JSP

```
<s:form action="targetAction" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
    <s:file name="file" />
    <s:fielderror fieldName="file" />
    <s:submit value="Start the upload" />
</s:form>
```

Target Action

```
public class TargetAction extends ActionSupport implements Validateable{

    private File file;
    private String fileContentType;
    private String fileFileName;
    /* Getters and setters */

    public String execute() {
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public void validate() {
        if (file==null){
            addFieldError("file","File is mandatory !! Please Retry");
        }
    }    
    /* when fieldErrors are added, INPUT result will be returned */ 

}
```

Target JSP

```
File <s:property value="fileFileName"/> successfully loaded.
```

You need to use the default InterceptorStack or ensure to have at least the Params, Upload, Workflow, Parameters, Validate Interceptors.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation Andrea Ligios, it is very helpful